# How to Redirect in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

us/my-blog?catid=1&id=404:my-thought-of-the-day-problem-of-traditional-education

```
RewriteRule ^\/?us/my-blog\?catid=\d+id=\d+\:(.*) http://www.takeshiyashima.com/us/my-blog/others/404-my-thought-of-the-day-problem-of-traditional-education/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have tried This rules. But this is not working. I Have lot of URL like this. I want to redirect them. What to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /us/my-blog\?catid=1&id=(.*)\:(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /us/my-blog/others/%3-%4? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Actually `I want http://www.takeshiyashima.com/us/my-blog?catid=1&id=404:my-thought-of-the-day-problem-of-traditional-education` this URL to Redirect in `http://www.takeshiyashima.com/us/my-blog/others/404-my-thought-of-the-day-problem-of-traditional-education` URL. @Howlin Your your codes are not working..

Comment: I click the url `http://www.takeshiyashima.com/us/my-blog?catid=1&id=404:my-thought-of-the-day-pr‌​oblem-of-traditional-education` but this is not redirecting to `http://www.takeshiyashima.com/us/my-blog/others/404-my-thought-of-the-day-probl‌​em-of-traditional-education`

Comment: Can you post the full contents of your htaccess file (into your question)

Comment: I cant because the word limitation here. But i give you the dropbox link where you can see my .htaccess file https://www.dropbox.com/s/a718snpi2b3xe3b/.htaccess ..

This file is a previous update, Not included your code. Please help me redirect this Url. https://www.dropbox.com/s/anvg3atbdw9aqvy/www-takeshiyashima-com_20140514T075551Z_CrawlErrors.csv

Comment: Try adding the rules above your first `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: Ok I'm Trying. Thank you.

Comment: sorry for disturbing you, Actually yesterday i had changed your `RewriteRule ^ /us/my-blog/others/%3-%4?` code to `/us/my-blog/others/404-my-thought-of-the-day-probl‌​‌​em-of-traditional-education` because `/us/my-blog/others/%3-%4?` was not working. But the problem is now all the `my-blog?catid=1&id` is linked to `/others/404-my-thought-of-the-day-probl‌​‌​em-of-traditional-education` this url. I want to send them individual URL. I don't want to send all the `my-blog?catid=1&id` to a single URL.